# Updated Facebook SDK to 0.7.0 - now it doesn't recognize SDKApplicationDelegate in AppDelegate or LinkShareContent?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have been using the Facebook SDK in order to allow users to share quotes to Facebook within my Swift app. My original (and working) version used the following in the AppDelegate:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        incrementAppRuns()
        return true
    }
```

and used the following in the relevant view controller:

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }

public func Share(){
        let myContent = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://example.com")!, quote: shareText)
        let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: myContent)
        shareDialog.mode = .native
        shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
        shareDialog.completion = { result in
            // Handle share results
        }

        do {
            try shareDialog.show()
        }
        catch{
        }
    }
```

However, after updating the SDK to 0.7.0 via Cocoa Pods the compiler now doesn't recognize either the SDKApplicationDelegate in the AppDelegate nor the LinkShareContent

Does anyone know why this is or what I should change to get it working (again)? Thanks in advance. I tried to look at the Facebook SDK documentation but wasn't able to locate any answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some further trawling and trial and error it appears that SDKApplicationDelegate has been renamed to ApplicationDelegate - making this change solved that issue. I also implemented the approach detailed here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/438

Essentially using FBSDKShareKit and using ShareLinkContent instead of LinkShareContent.